# vs 2008 crystal report toolbar overlapping menu

Tags: asp.net

when we are viewing our reports in the web application on Internet Explorer 10 using Compatibility mode, my menu items is getting overlapped by the toolbar of the crystal report.
My menu is an asp.net menu item control and it is placed in our master Page.

i have also tried to resolve the above by setting the z-index of the crystal report viewer to zero using a css class and setting the z-index of the asp menu control to 999 but it didn't worked.
can anyone help us on the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above issue is resolved by setting the style of the div tag  in the Master Page as follows

```
    <style type="text/css">

div
    {
        z-index: 9999;
    }
    #master_content_container *
    {
        z-index: 1;
    }
    /* other CSS Styling as appropriate... */</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
```

The idea is to set make sure that all other content has lower z-index than that on which the menu drops.

so i am setting a higher z-index value to the menu by setting it as

```
div {z-index:9999;}
```

in my master page

and the content of the content container is set to lower z-index value by setting the below

```
#master_content_container *
    {
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Some browser compatibility issues again raised with CR. You can do one thing like if possible,make the pdf at run time and show the same in iframe within the page.It will be better and cleaned view of all the records.